# É possível juntar 2 Arrays onde os indices são iguais em PHP?

Tags: php, array-associativo, merge

Boa Galera, estou com um problema Relacionado ao uso de arrays em PHP.
Estou fazendo uma busca de endereço no google maps, e o JSON me retorna o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Rua Vicente Velasco
                                    [short_name] => R. Vicente Velasco
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => route
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Uep5-S.2
                                    [short_name] => Uep5-S.2
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => political
                                            [1] => sublocality
                                            [2] => sublocality_level_1
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Presidente Prudente
                                    [short_name] => Pres. Prudente
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => São Paulo
                                    [short_name] => SP
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Brazil
                                    [short_name] => BR
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => country
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [formatted_address] => R. Vicente Velasco - Uep5-S.2, Pres. Prudente - SP, Brazil
                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [bounds] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => -22.0730082
                                            [lng] => -51.3799775
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => -22.0748567
                                            [lng] => -51.3807562
                                        )

                                )

                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [lat] => -22.0737691
                                    [lng] => -51.3804065
                                )

                            [location_type] => GEOMETRIC_CENTER
                            [viewport] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => -22.072583469709
                                            [lng] => -51.379017869709
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => -22.075281430292
                                            [lng] => -51.381715830291
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [partial_match] => 1
                    [place_id] => ChIJY3XgbV32k5QRQmh9Ne1joeo
                    [types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => route
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

Contudo, pra alguns endereços não está retornando o CEP, devido alguma falha de registro na própria Google. Com isso em meu projeto verifico se o CEP veio faltando e caso afirmativo faço uma segunda busca no WebService viacep.com.br, e de lá consigo obter o CEP, contudo preciso remontar esse array que veio do google unindo o campo do CEP que veio do ViaCEP pra retornar na minha função principal. Sabendo que a a posição do CEP no Array da google quando o endereço vem completo é:

```
['results'][0]['address_components'][6]['long_name']
```

Eu consigo montar um array com o mesmo padrão do da Google contendo somente o CEP (dado este retornado do WebService da ViaCep), com o valor na posição 6 e suas sub-chaves devidas:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 19036-068
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => postal_code
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Eu olhei a documentação do PHP mas não consegui aplicar nada (de forma prática) que faça essa união!
Tentei usar o array_merge_recursive(); Mas ele cria o segundo array como um índice diferente! =/

Gostaria de uma saída unindo esse dois como se os dados tivessem saído de um só lugar!

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que seu array do google esteja em uma variavel chamada `$resultGoogle` seria algo assim:

```
$itemAlvo = $resultGoogle['results'][0]['address_components'];
$itemAlvo[] = array(
    'long_name'=>$cep_do_viacep; //aqui vem o cep queobteve do ViaCEP
    'types'=> array('postal_code');
);
```

Pelo que entendi voce meio que quer injetar o cep no endereco, nao precisa juntar os 2 array voce pode so modificar o array do google

Comment: Olá Neuber, Vlw pela ajuda, mas ainda não deu certo! - você usou a palavra certa!... quero injetar esse dado no Array do google... Acontece que dessa forma que vc colocou o método esta retornando um erro de que não exitem no $resultGoogle o indice 6. E de fato quando a busca do google retorna sem o CEP ele não carrega a Chave [6]. teria alguma forma de incluir essas chaves nesse Array? o que pega é que são varios Arrays dentro de um Array, é toda uma estrutura e isso não sei mais o que fazer! estou quase pensando em desmontar e remontar o array do google todo num novo atraves de foreach! =(

Comment: @IsraelFelipeR.P. `estou quase pensando em desmontar e remontar o array do google todo num novo atraves de foreach!` e quase isso mas ao inves de recriar toda a estrutura voce vai injetar o que precisa. Usei como exemplo o indice 6 por que foi o que voce postou, mas pode simplesmente criar o indice que estiver faltando. mudei um pouco a resposta para exemplificar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde!... Cara com o exemplo que o Neuber Oliveira passou comecei a pensar em remontar o Array da google, baseado nessa forma de soma (+) entre os parâmetros, dai acabei de conseguido criar um código funcional, ficou meio "Grotesco", mas resolve o problema, talvez num foreach o código pudesse ficar menor ou mais direto a inserção! 
Basicamente o que fiz foi recrirar as chaves, conforme o padrão do original e dentro das sub-chaves onde se tratava de array recrei os índices e preenchi com o conteúdo do array $resultGoogle na chave específica!

Basicamente o padrão do Array do google é:

```
['results']
    [0]
        ['address_components']
            [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]

        ['formatted_address']
        ['geometry']
            ['bounds'], ['location'], ['location_type'], ['viewport']

        ['partial_match']
        ['place_id']
        ['types']
['status']
```

Só pra add a Chave [6] e seus valores Segue o código que gerei - baseado na Solução apresentada pelo Neuber Oliveira:

```
$itemModificar = array(
    'results' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'address_components' => $resultGoogle['results'][0]['address_components'] + 
                        array(6 => array('long_name' => $nBusca[0]['cep'],'types' => array(0 =>'postal_code'))
                        ),
                        'formatted_address' => $resultGoogle['results'][0]['formatted_address'],
                        'geometry' => array($resultGoogle['results'][0]['geometry']),
                        'partial_match' => $resultGoogle['results'][0]['partial_match'],
                        'place_id' => $resultGoogle['results'][0]['place_id'],
                         'types' => $resultGoogle['results'][0]['types'],),
    ),
    'status' => $resultGoogle['status']
);
```

Por enquanto essa solução resolve o problema, mas ainda estou encabulado de não haver uma forma mais simples ou direta!

Se alguém souber um código diferente, dentro das boas práticas, seria interessante de usar!

Por hora Agradeço de mais a Luz que vc me deu Neuber!
abrss! =P

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de conseguir uma forma mais prática!...
Não sei como não pensei nisso!... cabeça quente de mais acaba deixando passar o óbvio!
A saída mais certo é chamar o índice ['address_components'] e fazer com que ele receba os mesmo componentes acrescidos dos novos dados!

Segue o código mais direto:

```
$resultGoogle['results'][0]['address_components'] = 
$resultGoogle['results'][0]['address_components'] +
array(
    6 => array('long_name' => $nBusca[0]['cep'], 
    'types' => array(0 => 'postal_code')
    )
);
```

Fazendo assim ele mantêm todos os dados e inclui apenas o array novo no final da lista de arrays do índice ['address_components'], claro que para isso devo criar o array de indice [6] e criar suas sub-chaves ['long_name'] e ['types']!

Acredito agora que não deve ter outro método mais simples que isso!... de Todo modo fica ai a Solução!

Agradeço as contribuições! =D
Abraços!